# Can't upload images to my website

Tags: html, image, src

So, I looked it up but couldn't find a previous forum hat addressed my issue so hopefully you lovely people can help me out. I can't upload images on the site that I'm trying to build. 
This is the code I'm using:

On my computer I've set up a my directory like this:

/Documents/Development/Practise/img/unnamed-01.jpg

This is the first website I've every built so all the help and advice is greatly appreciated... have I set up my directory wrong? Is there a certain way I should set up before I build my site? I'd love to get my images up :)

Sam

Comment: <img/unnamed-01.jpg alt="The Boast Looking Cute">

Comment: Should be <img src="img/unnamed-01.jpg" alt="The Boast Looking Cute">` (Assuming this HTML is running from the `Practise` directory)

Comment: this is wrong, there is no 'src' attribute on your 'img'. Also, the path to use as your src is dependent on where the image is relative to your page. (my comment is not for @Mike's answer)

Comment: My apologies, that is exactly how it is in my code (with the <img src= )

Comment: See I think my problem is that I dont understand how the code reads my computer

Comment: what directory is your page in?

Comment: I might be able to trouble shoot this thing myself if I understood that part better.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_src.asp

Comment: when I save it, it creates a new file on my desktop\

Comment: @user3470825 - Do you have a web server?  Where is your HTML file?  In the `Practise` folder?  Do other images/resources load?  Do you get a *Missing Image* icon, or just nothing at all?

Comment: @user3470825 - Copy the HTML file into your `Practise` directory and run it from there.

Comment: My HTML file is on my desktop because everytime I save it , it goes there. If I drag and drop it into my practise folder then it won't read my css (which is also in the practise folder when I do that)

Comment: ok its reading my css now.. never mind. Still no image tho

Comment: Everything is now in my practise folder but still no image

Comment: Can you add your *exact* HTML to your question please?

Comment: Yes

<img src="/img/unnamed-01.jpg alt="The Boaster is Looking Cute">

Comment: You're missing an ending quote.  Also, take out the first `/` - <img src="img/unnamed-01.jpg" alt="The Boaster is Looking Cute">

Comment: True.. still didn't work though... I double checked all my file names and I have everything correct. I feel like it as something to do with the way I set up my directory but I don't understand it that well and I think that a bit of the problem. I appreciate all the help nevertheless!

Comment: Basically, all the paths are relative to the directory the HTML file is loaded from.  So, if there's an `img` directory off of *that* directory, everything should work.  Maybe put the image in the same directory as the HTML and just remove the path all together, just as a test.

Comment: Nope that didn't work either. Its weird because this to me should be a very simple function... Did I mention that this is my first website? Haha

Comment: Yup!  In that case, I'm completely out of ideas.  I suggesting posting the *entire* HTML in your question (not as a comment), along with a screen shot of the entire file structure (perhaps a DIR /B from the command prompt).  It's most likely a simple error.

Comment: Hey Mike, how do you open up a side bar in sublime text 2?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your image is stored in the /img/ directory.  You need to use the html tag of :

```
<img src="/img/unnamed-01.jpg" alt="description" />
```

That should display your image.